# How often Service Worker refreshes?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, create-react-app

I created an app with `create-react-app` which comes by default as a progressive web app (it loads this [file](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/src/registerServiceWorker.js)).

As a result now every time I deploy new content the app doesn't refresh. How often does it check for new content before serving the cached content? How can I choose how much time to save the cache?

Answer (score 2):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/lifecycle#the_first_service_worker), by default, a page's fetches won't go through a service worker unless the page request itself went through a service worker. So you'll need to refresh the page to see the effects of the service worker.

Here's an example wherein it adds image of a dog after 3 seconds.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
An image will appear here in 3 seconds:
<script>
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
    .then(reg => console.log('SW registered!', reg))
    .catch(err => console.log('Boo!', err));

  setTimeout(() => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = '/dog.svg';
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

Also, according to this [Updating your service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Updating_your_service_worker), if your service worker has previously been installed, but then a new version of the worker is available on refresh or page load, the new version is installed in the background, but not yet activated. It is only activated when there are no longer any pages loaded that are still using the old service worker. As soon as there are no more such pages still loaded, the new service worker activates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of your service worker code...however
assets you precache (in the install event typically) are there, unless you purge them.
Other URLs will pass through the fetch event handler (or go directly to the network if you do not have a handler attached).
Your logic to update the pre-cache will not update until you update the service worker. The install and activate events are only triggered once for each version of your service worker, thus they only trigger 1 time, ever, per version.
So you can either change the default precached assets (urls) and change your caching logic or abstract what files are pre-cached to a configuration source and dynamically update those assets.
It is tough to give you the actual answer to your problem since I don't know what your application's goals are.